# for loop to remove negative values from raster file in R using terra package

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, terra

I have raster image file. It has 348 bands.
I want to remove negative values from it and assign them as NA.

What I did is:

```
library(terra)

img1 <- rast("~/PATH/image_name")
img1

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3311, 678, 348  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 4.1, 4.1  (x, y)
extent      : (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : UTM Zone XY, Northern Hemisphere 
source      : img_msk_knl_brdf 
names       : 401.4~eters, 406.4~eters, 411.5~eters, 416.5~eters, 421.5~eters, 426.5~eters, ...
```

I tried

```
for (i in 1:nlyr(img1)) {
 img1[[i]][img1[[i]] < 0] <- NA
 }
```

and I tried this as well..

```
img1[img1 < 0] <- NA
```

both the times it continuously process in background.. but doesn't seem to do anything.. I have to forcefully terminate R session/RStudio.

What am I doing wrong here.?

Answer (score 1):

The `x[]<-` notation is nice for interactive use on small datasets. In principle, you could do `img1[img1 < 0] <- NA` (there is no need for a loop). However, you should generally avoid this pattern and use methods that are more direct, efficient and memory-safe. In this case that would be

```
x <- terra::clamp(img1, 0, values=FALSE)
```

For other cases see `terra::classify` and `terra::subst`. And if you are using loops like this for other things as well, have a closer look at the manual: `?terra`